# How to have easily the source code of @property?

Tags: python-3.x, decorator

All is in the title. I would like to have the code of the decorator `@property`. Where is it ?

Comment: Download the source code and use Ack to find the docstring.

Comment: Ack ? I don't understand.

Comment: http://beyondgrep.com/

Comment: That's look great? I will just try it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the advice of Blender, I find the C source using the line command `grep -lr "class property" *` in the directory of the source of Python.